# How to extract text from a RDD?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to extract text from a book. Sample line from the book.txt:

> **Author**:  However, Mary warns her mother that she hasn't changed since
>   she has worked last summer.
>   It was warm summer and the city was
>   filled with tourists that….

Here is the code that I have:

```
val bookRDD = sc.textFile(“file://test/book.txt”);
val sentenceRDD = bookRDD.filter(line => line.contains(“Author:”))
```

The code grabs all of the first line that contains  `Author:`

> *“**Author**:  However, Mary warns her mother that she hasn't changed since she has worked last summer.”*

This is good, but I need to grab the text that follows `Author:` and exclude `Author:`, so I have:

> However, Mary warns her mother that she hasn't changed since she has
>   worked last summer.

Can you help me write the code the grabs the text after the “**Author**:“?   I am trying to do this within a RDD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple String manipulation techniques that you can use here. You can go with `substring`, `replaceAll`, `split`(probably)

Here's one with `replaceAll`

```
rdd.filter( _.startsWith("Author:") )
   .map(_.replaceAll("Author:" , "").trim )
   .first

// String = However, Mary warns her mother that she hasn't changed since she has worked last summer.
```

Comment: This would probably be faster compared to other answers. You might want to remove ".first" from the answer

Comment: I used `first` to print the output.

Answer (score 3):

After filter you can map the rdd to replace the String `Author:` to blank.
e.g

```
val bookRDD = sc.textFile(“file://test/book.txt”);
val sentenceRDD = bookRDD.filter(line => line.contains(“Author:”)).map(line => line.replaceFirst("Author: ", ""))
```